# R Markdown 2 to EPUB How?

Tags: r, yaml, markdown, rstudio, epub

There is a suggestion on the RStudio blog that one can convert an R Markdown document into the EPUB format.  But I can't find any documentation on how to do this.  I suspect I may have to use pandoc arguments, but as someone new to R Markdown I am finding this a bit confusing.  And silly ideas of mine such as the YAML metadata below don't work.  All help appreciated. It would be particularly great if I could do this via the YAML metadata section of the R Markdown file.

```
---
title: "An epub"
output: epub_document
---
```

Comment: [?](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/084-pandoc.R#L28)

Answer (score 5):

With the `bookdown` package installed, you can specify a version of the following output format in  the yaml header:

```
output:
    bookdown::epub_book:
      number_sections: true
```

There are a number of other options.  See [Epub options](https://rdrr.io/cran/bookdown/man/epub_book.html). A quirk of my version of Reader for Mac (2.0.02.15180) is that $p$ appears as `pp`, and $\alpha$ appears as `α\alpha`.  With Calibre, it imports without problem.

An alternative is to make a new RMarkdown custom format (until some kind soul makes a custom format for EPub that they're willing to share!). All the documentation you should need to make this happen is here:

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_custom_formats.html

It's technically true that you can add Pandoc arguments to coerce one of the existing output documents to spit out an EPub book. For instance, try this:

```
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--to", "epub"]
```

You'll find that the `.html` that's emitted is actually an EPub book! But it's unlikely to look nice or work correctly, because all of the knitr options and Pandoc options set by `html_document` are designed to produce HTML documents, not books.

Comment: Thanks.  And a plea to all kind souls to help out!

Comment: Did @Jonathan just volunteer to be that kind soul :-)

Answer (score 2):

I do it using `pandoc` from the command line and (in my case) it works just perfect.

Here is the command line I use:

```
$ pandoc --mathjax -s --highlight-style tango FILE.Rmd --to epub -o OUTPUT.epub
```

Comment: It is indeed working perfect. Working well for `.md` files as well.